# Wamp: error installing magento 2, missing PHP extensions?

Tags: php, magento, wamp

Hey guy im trying to install magento 2.0.2 on wamp running on windows 10 but when try to install magento the php extension check shows 6 missing extensions...i checked the extensions on the php.ini and they where not commented and fully loaded...i dont understand why magento shows this error...

Comment: Please provide error messages, relevant portions of your running configuration, and verify that phpinfo() shows these extensions are loaded.

Comment: what is the actual error? please see [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Just because an extension is not commented out in php.ini does not mean it will be loaded. There can be other pre-requisites that are not fulfilled.

To see if an extension is loaded you should to look at the output of the `phpinfo()` command to see if it is properly loaded,

Answer (score -1):

Use below code to remove error

Magento 2 PHP Extensions Check Error

Go to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12 Copy all icu....dll`

File and Paste in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`

Restart All Services